# Create ARFaceGeometry from BlendShape dictionary

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, iphone-x

I am trying to create an ARKit Mesh based on the blendShape dictionary I create (in a Unity script). Basically, I want to get a mesh and modify one value in the dictionary and create the geometry back using this new dictionary.

I found the method [init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry/2928204-init) in the ARFaceGeometry documentation but I do not understand how exactly to call it.

With the help of Face Tracking examples on the [Unity blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/11/03/arkit-face-tracking-on-iphone-x/) I have come up with code that looks like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.XR.iOS;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RetrieveBlendShapesARKit : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UnityARSessionNativeInterface m_session;
    Dictionary<string, float> currentBlendShapes;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        currentBlendShapes["eyeBlink_L"] = 1.0f;

        Debug.Log("---------------Get ARKit Mesh Start-------------------");
        m_session = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface();
        ARKitFaceTrackingConfiguration config = new ARKitFaceTrackingConfiguration();
        config.alignment = UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity;
        config.enableLightEstimation = true;

        if (config.IsSupported)
        {
            m_session.RunWithConfig(config);
            UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFaceAnchorAddedEvent += FaceAdded;
            UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFaceAnchorUpdatedEvent += FaceUpdated;
        }
    }

    void FaceAdded(ARFaceAnchor anchorData)
    {
        anchorData.faceGeometry.init(currentBlendShapes);
    }

    void FaceUpdated(ARFaceAnchor anchorData)
    {
        anchorData.blendShapes = currentBlendShapes;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I get an error saying `ARFaceGeometry does not contain a definition of init` and I also get an error that I cannot assign blendShapes since it's read-only (I just thought of trying direct assignment which didn't work).

I would appreciate any help in using this `init` method, or any other way to create the ARKit mesh on iPhone using a custom blendShape dictionary through Unity.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?